# View text version of remote server SSL certificate from linux command line

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, openssl

Does anyone know of a linux one-liner that can be used to download an SSL certificate from a remote server and decode it to text?

I think the last step would involve `openssl x509 -text -noout` but the `-in` part of this would be from a remote site somehow rather than a local file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this pipe:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect host:port | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

The command `openssl s_client` will perform the SSL handshake with the host and print out the certificate as a string in PEM format (among other things). The  `openssl x509` will convert this certificate string into a human-readable form. The `echo` is just there to trigger the close of the connection after the SSL handshake, so that the command will not hang waiting for input.

Comment: Funny use of `echo`. A redirect `< /dev/null` would be more idiomatic, I think.

Comment: Sure, this works too.